# When is EINTR error returned?

Tags: c, operating-system

I saw the code(read, write system call) that handling EINTR error.
I understood interrupt occur in two cases. First, it occur every time quantum for schedule. Second, it occur by signal. But everyone in stackoverflow said just signal case only.

So, My question is that EINTR is returned just by signal? or returned by something else?

Comment: The answer to that question is compiler/library specific. Whenever you call a library function, you should read the documentation and the code, if available, to determine what kinds of error values it is likely to return and plan accordingly.

Comment: Time-based scheduling doesn't interrupt a process in the sense of generating EINTR — it simply means that another process is given a chance to run.  Besides, most of the system calls for which EINTR is a possibility are 'long duration' calls; things like waiting for I/O or a signal to arrive.  It also depends on how you've set signal handlers; `SA_RESTART` is relevant here.

Comment: Do not confuse hardware interrupts with POSIX signals. The former are a hardware implementation detail in computers and microcontrollers, and the latter are a way of interrupting an userspace process or a thread (by another thread in the process, by the kernel, or by another process). Think of "to interrupt" as a verb! `EINTR` is an error code produced when a "blocking" syscall (an operation that cannot be immediately performed but involves some kind of a wait) is interrupted by a signal delivery to the same thread, and the signal handler was set allowing such interruptions to occur.

Comment: Maybe helpful -- Why EINTR ?-- Because "EINTR error to give the program an opportunity to handle the signal without the restriction on signal-safe functions" -- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/#interrupted-system-calls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you mention `read` and `write`, I'll assume you're referring to POSIX-compliant operating systems and answer for those. As [jwdonahue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150445/jwdonahue) has pointed out, it may be different for different functions and operating systems.

A return value of `EINTR` means that the function was interrupted by a signal before the function could finish its normal job. The signal itself may or may not have been caused by an interrupt. Let me elaborate, because the terms "interrupt", "signal" and "interrupted" are subtle.

A signal is simply a particular kind of inter-process communication. It allows the kernel to interrupt the execution of processes and therefore, processes to interrupt each other.

An interrupt, on the other hand, is a lower level, often hardware related phenomenon that originates in the processor. In POSIX environments an interrupt is often turned into a signal by the kernel and sent to relevant processes.

So `EINTR` means a signal was received. The signal caused the process to be "interrupted" (not to be confused with an interrupt). The signal may or may not have been caused by an underlying interrupt. For example, `SIGSEGV` and `SIGBUS` are caused by interrupts while `SIGINT` (confusingly enough) is caused by software - generally when a Ctrl-C is sent to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused with interrupts, which is an asynchronous event, and EINTR which is just a error code.

Not all interrupted code result in errno being set to EINTR. errno is set to EINTR when some system calls are interrupted and the system is not in a position to resume the system call after interrupt handling. Developer may choose to retry the system call again by checking errno.

That said, any user defined function can set errno to EINTR too without any interrupts in the picture.

For eg:

```
int foo () {
    //do_some_stuff_here
    errno = EINTR;
    return -1;
}
```

is perfectly valid (may not be too useful, but valid).